# Log Handled Exceptions in ASP.NET with ELMAH

Tags: elmah

I'm using ELMAH for an ASP.Net web application and it works fine

but I need to log the handled exceptions but not manually , I do not want to write in the

try/catch block any code to log the exception with the ELMAH

is there any way to make custom solution to log exceptions that are handled in the code by

ELMAH

thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The best that can be done in this case is, in each catch block, rethrow the exception like this

```
try
{
.............
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
............
throw;
}
```

Elmah will handle the exception raised from the catch block as unhandled exception and will log it automatically.

Comment: I know that but i need instead of log the exception by elmah in the catch block , i need this to be done automatic such the unhandled exceptions

Comment: I think that we don't need the **ErrorLog_Filtering** event as any unhandled exception will be logged by elmah with no code , for throwing the exception from the catch block again after handling it I think it is not convenient for me , the best solution for me is the try-catch block and some event that triggered with any exception which is handled or not , so I can write my code to log the handled exception for it . thanks alot @Ajit Goel

Comment: That is right. The errorlog_filtering event does not need to be added. Elmah will handle the exception raised from the catch block as unhandled exception and will log it automatically.

Comment: @MahmoudSamir: Can you please accept the answer if this is what you want?

Comment: sorry,the solution doesn't fit with me :(